# How to bind data from a List<class> to Picker element in Xamarin

Tags: c#, list, xamarin, drop-down-menu, picker

I have a list (`List<Customer> l_Customer`) that gets data from an API. `<Customer>` class includes `fullname` that is of string value. How can i get only the full names from that list and display them on the Picker's dropdown list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a simple example for your reference with MVVM.

Xaml:

```
  <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding l_Customer}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding fullname}"></Picker>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class Page14 : ContentPage
{
    public Page14()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new CustomerViewModel();
    }
}
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public List<Customer> l_Customer { get; set; }
    public CustomerViewModel()
    {
        l_Customer = new List<Customer>()
        {
            new Customer(){ fullname="A"},
            new Customer(){ fullname="B"},
            new Customer(){ fullname="C"},
        };
    }
}
public class Customer
{
    public string fullname { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource#populating-a-picker-with-data-using-data-binding) to do exactly this in the docs

```
<Picker Title="Select a customer"
    ItemsSource="{Binding l_Customer}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding fullname}" />
```

or in code

```
var picker = new Picker { Title = "Select a Customer" };
picker.SetBinding(Picker.ItemsSourceProperty, "l_Customer");
picker.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("fullname");
```

Comment: Creating a viewmodel is a useful method? Also does it need to be an IList<> with `new ObservableCollection<Customer>` in order to bind the  values to the picker from the viewmodel?